# finding whether a graph is ascending or descending overally

Tags: math, statistics

Assuming we have a price chart in terms of time, how do we know if this chart has been overally ascending or descending lately?

Comment: Compare the first and last points?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean *exactly* by

> has been overally ascending or descending lately?

One straightforward way to do this would be to fit a linear regression model to the range that you are interested in. The slope of the regression line will then answer this question.